# Why Apache runs as unprivileged user?

Tags: malware, webserver, apache, privilege-escalation

Apache Web server as a security measure relinquishes its system privileges and runs as a normal unprivileged user before accepting clients over a networks. My Question is

- How this measure prevents or restrains bugs to be exploited by malware.
- What is idea behind this approach

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the context of www-data is a lot less privileged than the one of root. For instance as a root user you can alter a lot more configuration files, add or remove users, read protected folders, etc...

As www-data you cannot do this, so even when exploited the attacker can only use all resources and files available to www-data. This helps contain the attack (obviously privilege escalation cannot be stopped if exploits exist).